# Google map not coming despite no errors

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to load google map in emulator for a given latitude and longitude.

Map is loading in the emulator but no marker is coming and same view is shown always.

i have followed the [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-marker-at-user-input-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map-android-api-v2/). Below is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
double latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lat", 0);
    double longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("lng", 0);

    Log.d("Zumbare","lat value : "+latitude);
    Log.d("Zumbare","lng value : "+longitude);

    LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options.position(position);
    options.title("Position");
    options.snippet("Latitude:"+latitude+",Longitude:"+longitude);
    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));


    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    GoogleMap googleMap = fm.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

    googleMap.addMarker(options);
    CameraUpdate updatePosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
    CameraUpdate updateZoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(4);
    googleMap.moveCamera(updatePosition);
    googleMap.animateCamera(updateZoom);

}
```

Below is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.maptest.gmap" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.app.maptest.gmap.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.maptest.gmap.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCInpkx8MO-lD4AMR4aUYns3tVvUMjIH1k" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_activity2" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone help me where the problem is..

Edit :

Yes, I am fetching lat lng of a city and logs are coming as..

```
1885-1885/com.app.maptest.gmap D/Zumbare﹕ lat value : 16.506174
03-29 16:20:54.602    1885-1885/com.app.maptest.gmap D/Zumbare﹕ lng value : 80.648015
```

Edit2:

I am using android studio and added the google play service in gradle file as below.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are fetching correct lat and lang?

Comment: Yes, I am fetching right lat long.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial that you followed is outdated. `play-services` now is `6.5.87`.

Please try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, you will finally get a map on your phone.

`MainAcitivity`, sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static LatLng goodLatLng = new LatLng(37, -120);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private EditText et_address, et_finalAddress;
    LatLng addressPos, finalAddressPos;
    Marker addressMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et_address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        et_finalAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalAddressEditText);


        // Initial Map
        try {

            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        // Put a dot on my current location
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        // 3D building
        googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        // Get zoom button
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(goodLatLng)
                .title("Hello"));
    }
```

For more details, please refer to my github [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMapExample-android).

[image]

Comment: I am looking to get the same in Emulator and not in device.

Comment: As `Emulator` you need to set up `play service` which you can refer to [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Maps-Fragment-Guide)